# syntax error with nokogiri, unexpected '.' after nokogiri::CSS object

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I just begin to learn scraping, and get the error "   unexpected '.' after '#'  ".
Using pry, when I put the line that causes this problem (i.e. page.css("div[@class='wrapper']/div/div//ul[17]/li[4]").text()), it works.

I tried to replace page.css("...") by page.xpath("...") but it doesn't return anything.

```
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"
require "pry"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.website_i_want_datas_from.com"))

myscrapp_2 = []

for k in (1..500) do

    ((page.css("div[@class='wrapper']/div/div//ul[k]/li[4]").text() =~ /@/) != nil ? myscrapp_2 << page.css("div[@class='wrapper']/div/div//ul[k]/li[4]").text()
 : myscrapp_2 << page.css("div[@class='wrapper']/div/div//ul[k]/li[5]").text())

    binding.pry
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rather use this kind of syntax to scrape elements :

```
scrape = []
page.xpath('your/xpath').each do |node|
        scrape.push(node.text)
end
```